# GCI (and LC server) not working Ubuntu server 20.04 on Raspberry 4 8GB

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, raspberrypi, cgi

it seems CGI is not working, and if I'm correct it should work out of the box with Ubuntu server 20.04 64bits.

- I installed Ubuntu following this tut: [how to install Ubuntu server 20.04 on Raspberry](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#community)
- Then I followed this fine tut, because I used similar before on a VPS, except for ISPConfig  because I don't need that for this: [The Perfect Server with Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-ubuntu-20.04-with-apache-php-myqsl-pureftpd-bind-postfix-doveot-and-ispconfig/)
- Tried all I could find on activating CGI, but each time I get the message that it's already activated.
- Added also some into 000-default.conf to get LC server (Livecode via cgi) working.

  ```
   ### ***LC Server*** ###
   #ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
   ScriptAlias /livecode-cgi/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
   <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   </Directory>

   <Directory “/var/www/”>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AddHandler livecode-script .lc
   Action livecode-script /cgi-bin/livecode-community-server
   </Directory>
   ### ***************************** ###
  ```

I also tried the ScriptAlias and Directory directives using /user/lib/cgi-bin/, no difference.
Even ruling all these LC addition out in the conf file and just trying to use a simple cgi file, it's getting displayed as text instead of executed and yes it is executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ''
echo 'CGI Bash example<br>'
echo `df -h / | grep -v Filesystem`
```

There are no errors logged in apache2 error log files concerning this.
So to me it just looks like cgi is just not working and hence that is why LC server is able to run either. PHP works flawless.

Anyone any idea why cgi is not working correctly?
I'm strungling with this for days now, searching on so many websites which are all simply saying do this and do that, and it just doesn't.
Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, you have your CGI files in `/var/www/cgi-bin`, correct?

Comment: I have a testcgi.cgi file in that foldere correct. The .lc files which use the cgi livecode-community-server are normally located in htdocs or public-html as these function likewise as PHP files. This has previously worked correct on an VPS with exact settings.

Comment: I think that suexec is the culprit. Following the perfect server tutorial, suexec is installed. I decided to not install  ISPconfig to maybe spare some resources. Uninstalling suexec and rebooting did not help, so re-installed it. And went on now installing ISPconfig3 anyway. It seems ISPconfig3 uses this suexec and also configures this and a lo of other thins. SInce this also worked previously on the VPS. I'm going ahead with this and hope to get it fixed that way. THanks.